# Line break height

Tags: android, textview, line-breaks

I have the following TextView, and I use it in a ListView:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:textSize="16px"
    android:minHeight="5px"/>
```

The TextItem contains line breaks, and this line breaks are... too big: it's like having an empty line. Is there a way to change the height of the line break?

Regards,
ProgVal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, there was actually two line breaks. I was replacing the 
 of a downloaded HTML file by line breaks, but... there was already a line break after every 
.